# Classification of this nonlinear PDE into elliptic, hyperbolic, etc.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I wanted to know how one would classify a nonlinear PDE into elliptic, hyperbolic or parabolic forms.
The particular PDE I would like to know about would be

\begin{align}
  \partial_t u &= D(\partial^2_{x} +\partial^2_y) u + AS((\partial_x u)^2+(\partial_y u)^2) +AA (\partial_xu)(\partial_yu) + c(1-c)
\end{align}

Comment: Why do you think this equation is nonlinear?

Comment: I guess my notation was misleading. Now the (grad) squared terms are clearer.

Comment: Thanks.  What are $D$, $A$, $c$, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

> The particular PDE I would like to know about would be 
>   $$\partial_t u = D(\partial^2_{x} +\partial^2_y) u + AS((\partial_x)^2+(\partial_y)^2)u +AA \partial_x\partial_yu + c(1-c)$$

---

The classification of Partial Differential Equations into *elliptic*, *parabolic* and *hyperbolic* is formally defined for ***linear second order PDEs*** only.

Then, assuming $u=u(x,y)$,  you can determine its type by bringing it to its **canonical form**

$$  \mathsf{A}\,u_{xx} + 2\,\mathsf{B}\,u_{xy} + \mathsf{C}\,u_{yy} + 
   \mathsf{D}\, u_{x} + \mathsf{E} \, u_{y} + \mathsf{F} = 0    $$

In that case, if

1. $\mathsf{B}^2 - 4\mathsf{A}\mathsf{C} <0$, then the equation is *elliptic*,
2. $\mathsf{B}^2 - 4\mathsf{A}\mathsf{C} =0$, then the equation is *parabolic*,
3. $\mathsf{B}^2 - 4\mathsf{A}\mathsf{C} >0$, then the equation is *hyperbolic*.

One way to apply this classification to a *general* (e.g. *quasilinear*, *semilinear*, *nonlinear*) second order PDE is to linearize it. It is actually unclear whether your original PDE is linear or not:

- If $A$, $D$, and $S$ are **constants**, or **functions** which depend on $(x,y,t)$, then the equation is linear,
  so you can write out the canonical form and determine the type of PDE.
- If, however, $A$, $D$, and $S$ are **(nonlinear) functions**, which depend on $u$ or its derivatives, then
  you might have to compute a linearization of PDE first, and then determine its type.

**Note** that for the  classification purposes we do not make a distinction between  *spatial* ($x,y$) and *temporal* ($t$) variables.

In your case function $ u = u(x,y,t) $ depends, apparently, on three variables. 
This means that you will have to use generalized classification for PDEs defined on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, which can be found in the [Wikipedia article about PDEs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_differential_equation#Equations_of_second_order).

Comment: How would I compute it's linearization?
I am not sure how to linearize these terms:
\begin{align}
  \partial_t u &= AS((\partial_x u)^2+(\partial_y u)^2) 
\end{align}

Comment: If by $ AS\Big( \big(\partial_{x} u \big)^{2} + \big(\partial_{x} u \big)^{2} \Big) $ you mean $ A\cdot S\cdot  \Big( \big(\partial_{x} u \big)^{2} + \big(\partial_{x} u \big)^{2} \Big) $, where $\cdot$ is regular multiplication,  and if $A$ and $S$ do not depend on $u$ or its derivatives, then you already have it in the linear form. 
You might want to rewrite as
$$
A\cdot S\cdot (\partial_x u)^2+A\cdot S\cdot (\partial_y u)^2 -  \partial_t u  = 0
$$
though, thus obtaining the canonical form of your PDE.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. The terms I emphasized are gradient squared terms. They are clearly nonlinear as they are square terms. How can they be linearized . ( there is all the u(1-u) bit at the end which is nonlinear.)

Comment: If you are talking about  treating $$\begin{align} \partial_t u &= AS((\partial_x u)^2+(\partial_y u)^2)  \end{align}$$  as an equation by itself, then it is of the first order, and the _elliptic/parabolic/hyperbolic_ classification is not applicable.
If, on the other hand, you are viewing these terms as a part of the original equation, then they play no role in 2-nd order PDE classification. The original equation is *semilinear*, i.e. it it linear w.r.t second order terms. The coefficients in front of $u_{xx},u_{yy}$, and $u_{xy}$ are the only ones used in determining the type of equation.